# Oracle function for retrieving data from Baan tables

Tags: oracle, function

I am trying to build an Oracle function which returns all data from a Baan table. Input for the function should be the table name and the company number. Something like `select * from table(f_tabledata(tccom001,100))`.
This should return all data from Baan table ttccom001100.
The reason for this is I have some rather complex stored procedures in which many Baan generic tables are used (without the company-extension). This SP's are used in SSRS reports, in which the user should be able to select the company number. I have to admit, being a Baan expert, I am not that familiar with Oracle. Any idea on how my function should look like would be welcome! Any other idea also would be great as well.

Comment: You should use a pipelined function. However the datatype returned by f_tabledata should be the same for all tables. For a different table you should have another function.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Florin. I am looking for a more generic solution though. Hope someone has the clue.

Comment: It is possible to build a pipelined table function that is completely generic.  It is, however, insanely complex code.  If you're a newcomer to PL/SQL, I would strongly advise you to choose a different path.  For example, perhaps you just want to use dynamic SQL in your code rather than building a dynamic pipelined table function.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285685/returning-a-table-without-pre-defining-column-names-from-a-pl-sql-function/26286247#26286247

Comment: Thank you very much, Justin, I do appreciate your advise. And the link. I am still hoping there is a more simple or an already worked-out solution available. I suppose there MUST be a Baan-dba somewhere on this globe who faced this issue before me, picked up the glove... and won!

Comment: Regarding the workaround in my SP-code: Teh current solution for the time being I have created: In the Stored Procedure I have a query like 'select * from tccom001', but more complicated, with about 20 different Baan-tables. On the top of this SP, I execute an extra SP which creates or replaces the synonym tccom001 for 'baan.t'||<table>||<comp>, which results into 'baan.ttccom001100'. The variabe comp is set by the user of an SSRS-report. I execute this extra SP for all the tables I need in the main SP.

Comment: The problem is, when different users at a time start the report for different companies, they overwrite each others synonyms (all users use the same db-account for reading the Oracle database).